# Magento site suddenly mail not coming to user and admin

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email, smtp

Hello My magento site have suddenly mailing process not working. Please help me I have SMTP. It's working fine but now mails are not working. Please shortout my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your mail is working or not for this you need to place this script in the root of your site:

```
<?php

// Send mail, the Magento way:
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

// Create a simple contact form mail:
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->loadDefault('contacts_email_email_template');
$data = new Varien_Object();
$data->setData(    
    array(
        'name' => 'Your name',
        'email' => 'mymail@mail.com',
        'telephone' => '7856512345',
        'comment' => 'This is a test'
    )
);
$vars = array('data' => $data);

// Set sender information:
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(
    Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId));
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(
    Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId));
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Test mail');
$email = 'yourmail.com';
// Send the mail:
$output = $emailTemplate->send($email, null, $vars);
var_dump($output);
?>
```

Change $email = 'yourmail.com'; to your correct email id and save it in a file called emailtest.php, and simply call it in the browser like this http://www.yourdomain.com/emailtest.php

Now you should see a true -message when Magento was able to send the mail and false  if not.
If this work check your cron setting for more on cron  [see here.](http://trive.digital/writing/magento-emails-not-sent)

Comment: Hi, I have got bool(false).  I think not working.

Comment: @ChirayuVyas there might be server issue check all seting or contact to your sever support team hope they will resolve the issue.good luck

Comment: @Aruendra I have VPS server.